# magento top nav categories change root

Tags: php, magento

I have list of categories, and they showing in top menu

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
```

Magento displays all of categories, i need to display only a child categories with root category id, for example 23,
i find in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu

```
 $this->_menu = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node(array(), 'root', new Varien_Data_Tree());
```

but i dont know how i can change root category. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `System->Configuration->Catalog->Category Top Navigation` and set the value `1` for the field `Maximal Depth`.